# Are there examples of passengers' Micro SD cards or USB flash drives surviving crashes?

Tags: accident-investigation

Are there any well-documented cases of Micro SD cards or USB flash drives surviving 100% hull loss crashes? I'm asking about cards held by passengers, not ones that are part of the aircraft's systems.

Comment: are you asking for flash storage from PAX or from crew/avionics?

Comment: @selectstriker2: from PAX

Comment: The SIM cards would survive almost any crash unless they end up in fire or get crushed via some other article. The reason is that they have little mass and are really small.

Comment: @GürkanÇetin: Of course, "end up in fire" and "crushed" are rather common outcomes for things involved in an aircraft crash...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Some videos where recovered from the germanwings crash. See this article talking about it: [link](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/germany/11508250/Video-shows-cabin-chaos-in-seconds-before-Alps-crash.html)

The video can now easily be found online. I recommend against it tho.